# NGINX context redirect

Tags: nginx

> I want to redirect my NGINX request to different context however I
>   want my request URL shown to user to remian same. eg:-
>
> If user enters https://example.com/test it should redirect to
>   https://example.com/test1 but URL shown to user should remain same i.e.
>   https://example.com/test.
>
> I try to use below configuration but it changes my request URL.

```
location /test {
                                 return 301 $scheme://$host/token/;
                                 $remote_addr;
                                  }
```

Comment: what is `token` here ?

Comment: token is name of new context where I want to redirect my request

Answer (score 1):

Use [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) module then,

```
location /test {
 rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/token/ permanent; # permanent if needed
}
```

If you want to control the redirect from your application use [X-Accel-Redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-redirect)

Comment: Sorry for late comment. This will redirect my request but it will be visible to user also. What I want is the request URL should remain unchanged when it gets redirected to new one.

Comment: use https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-redirect